# Unable to set correct maven dependency for spring-jms

Tags: spring, maven, activemq-classic, eclipse-wtp, spring-jms

I have a project involving spring-mvc/jms/active-mq. Getting the following exception when trying to deploy to Tomcat 7.26 within Eclipse Juno:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory] for bean with name 'cachingConnectionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/authmgr-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory
```

pom.xml

```
<project>   
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <org.springframework.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    <org.springframework.security.version>3.1.3.RELEASE</org.springframework.security.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.1.9.Final</hibernate.version>
    <org.apache.tiles.version>2.2.2</org.apache.tiles.version>
</properties>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>repository.springsource.release</id>
        <name>SpringSource Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.springsource.org/release</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>repository.jboss.org-public</id>
        <name>JBoss.org Maven repository</name>
        <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-mail</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
        <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-all</artifactId>
        <version>5.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xbean</groupId>
        <artifactId>xbean-spring</artifactId>
        <version>3.13</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Relevant section of spring config:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms"
xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm" xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm
http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm.xsd
http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core
http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

<!-- JMS -->
<amq:connectionFactory id="connectionFactory"
    brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" />

<bean id="cachingConnectionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
    <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="100" />
</bean>

<!-- Integration with Focus -->
<amq:queue id="appointmentsImportQ" physicalName="FOCUS.APPOINTMENTS.EXPORT.QUEUE" />

<bean id="appointmentsImportMessageListener"
    class="com.test.authmgr.service.messaging.AppointmentsImportMessageListener">
</bean>

<bean id="appointmentsImportMsgListenerContainer"
    class="org.springframework.jms.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="cachingConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="destination" ref="appointmentsImportQ" />
    <property name="messageListener" ref="appointmentsImportMessageListener" />
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="1" />
</bean>

<bean id="oxmAppointmentsImportMessageConverter"
    class="org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MarshallingMessageConverter">
    <property name="marshaller" ref="appointmentsImportMarshaller" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="appointmentsImportMarshaller" />
</bean>

<oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="appointmentsImportMarshaller">
    <oxm:class-to-be-bound
        name="com.test.authmgr.focus.integration.jaxb.Profile" />
</oxm:jaxb2-marshaller>
</beans>
```

If the spring-framework's version is lowered to say 3.1.x then I start to get `ClassNotFoundException` for other spring-jms stuff like `MessageConverter`.

I thought maybe something is wrong with the wtp plugin, however, running from the command line:

```
mvn clean package
```

results in:

```
package org.springframework.jms.support.converter does not exist
```

I can verify that the package does exist in `.m2` and `spring-jms-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar` does contain the said package.

`ActiveMQ` is running as a stand alone server and I can log in `http:localhost:8161/admin`.

What is missing from this configuration? Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have some other Spring jar versions on the classpath (maybe in one of the tomcat shared classloaders). Add `-verbose` to `CATALINA_OPTS` to see which jar(s) classes are being loaded from.

**EDIT**

Also take a look at the dependency graph in the eclipse POM editor - you may have to exclude Spring deps brought in transitively by other projects.

Comment: I'll try it, however this won't explain the error from the command line: mvn clean package.

Comment: I found the problem. Had test scoped spring-jms. Blind cut & paste. Accepting your answer as it put me on the right path.